# Powershell Select-String on a File Adds Unwanted Metadata

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm trying to filter out service accounts in a file containing user accounts, one per line:

```
"svc.test"
"test.user"
"test.user2"
```

Select-String adds unwanted metadata:

```
C:\Output> select-string -Path C:\Output\tmp.csv 'svc' -NotMatch   
tmp.csv:415:"test.user"  
tmp.csv:416:"test.user2"
```

I just want:

```
"test.user"  
"test.user2"
```

How do I do this?

--- Update ---
Here is the result of the Get-Member cmdlet:

```
 PS C:\Output> select-string -Path C:\Output\tmp.csv 'svc' -NotMatch|get-member


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition                                                       
----         ---------- ----------                                                       
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                   
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()                                                
GetType      Method     type GetType()                                                   
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)                            
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)             
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}                                           
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}                                       
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}                                           
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}                                        
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}        
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}                                           
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

I need the data. How do I output the line property data to a file?

Comment: Select-string outputs objects.  You should pipe that to Get-Member to see what the properties are.  One of them is the one you need.

Comment: as MikeShepard pointed out, `Select-String` outputs objects. if you only want part of each object ... Read The Friendly Manual for that cmdlet. [*grin*]

Comment: @wirelessben - have you tried looking at the value stored in `.Line` property? [*grin*]

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I don't know how to filter it. I'm a Linux guy used to filtering text files. Displaying and filtering properties of objects with powershell is foreign to me.

Comment: Check `Get-Help Select-String -Online` (like a Man Page). See -Raw (Available in PowerShell 7)

Comment: @wirelessben - please take a look at the Answer i just posted. ///// as more than one person has pointed out, you REALLY need to start reading the help for this stuff. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do things. [*grin*] the `Select-String` cmdlet always includes a good deal of metadata along with the matches. the object type is `matchinfo`, not `string`, so you need to get the *value* that you want ... and in this case, that value is contained in the `.Line` property of the objects.

what the code does ...

- sets the file name to use
- creates a list of items to exclude
- creates a regex OR of that list
  the `S-S` cmdlet defaults to using the `-Pattern` parameter for matches ... and that uses a regex pattern.
- creates a file to work with
- runs `Select-String` with a file for input, a regex pattern, and the `-NotMatch` switch parameter to reverse the match
- grabs the value in the `.Line` property for each object
- sends that to the `$Result` collection
- displays that collection on screen

the code ...

```
$FileName = "$env:TEMP\wirelessben_S-S_Demo.txt"

$ExcludeList = @(
    'line'
    'five'
    'seven'
    )
$RegexEL = $ExcludeList -join '|'

#region >>> create a file to work with
@'
the first line
2nd line, this one is
a third line
the fourth goes forth
one, two, five ... THREE sir!
the number of this line is six
seven
eight
number nine, number nine
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $FileName
#endregion >>> create a file to work with


$Result = (Select-String -LiteralPath $FileName -Pattern $RegexEL -NotMatch).Line

$Result
```

output ...

```
the fourth goes forth
eight
number nine, number nine
```

note that any line that contains `line`, `five`, or `seven` is excluded.

Comment: And there it is. "Put parentheses around the code that creates the object and add '.Line'", just like you would in a programming language. That's what I needed. Thank you, Lee. 
Btw, I did search long and hard for this documentation and never found it. This will help someone else who comes from another environment.

Comment: @wirelessben - you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// as for the help ... i have been playing with PoSh for so long that i likely see more in the help than is readily apparent. sorry about the nag! [*blush*]